# "Only 0 Left" message has suddenly appeared after 2.4.2 upgrade

Tags: configurable-product, inventory, magento2.4.2

As wrote in the title, after I've upgraded from Magento 2.4.1 to 2.4.2 the message "Only 0 Left" has suddenly appeared in the product page (configurable product).

I checked in **Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Inventory->Stock Options->Only X left Threshold** and it's set to **0**. I tried to set to **-1** but nothing's changed.

[image]

Any solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug affecting configurable products introduced by the new `Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductFrontendUi` module in Magento 2.4.2. You can read more about the issue here: https://github.com/magento/inventory/issues/3276

As a temporary solution you can disable the module which will remove the message.

```
bin/magento module:disable Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductFrontendUi
```

Comment: It seems to solve the issue for now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CSS to temporarily hide the "Only 0 Left"

.availability.only.configurable-variation-qty {
display: none !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

Modify vendor/magento/module-inventory-configurable-product-frontend-ui/view/frontend/web/js/configurable-variation-qty.js or extend this file

change from

```
if (response.qty !== null && response.qty > 0) {
```

to

```
if (response.qty !== null && parseFloat(response.qty) > 0) {
```

Credit goes to MarekCernak From https://github.com/magento/inventory/issues/3276 thread.